# if clause using image in datagridviewimagecolumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, if-statement

Is it possible to set IF case using the images present in the datagridviewimagecolumn?

```
Example:
If current row image = "Red.png"... show error msg  
If current row image = "Green.png"... Insert to database
```

Thank You!

Comment: needs more info.. what do you mean by current row image? Is it if the current selected row contains image?

Comment: For example, the Datagridview contains 2 column. 

1st-->Email 2nd-->Image to show whether Email is Valid (Red.png for Invalid, Green.png for Valid) When user click submit, i will go through the image column, if image shown is "Red.png", will inform user that it is invalid once more, and dont allow him to continue...

Comment: the images are been added to the DGV using "DGV.item(1,x).value = system.drawing.image.fromfile(strPath & "red.png")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in this fashion

Need to assign a Text to identify the image you are displaying in the **DataGridViewImageCell**, while adding the image just set the description for the cell

```
(dataGridView1[2, 2] as DataGridViewImageCell).Description = "Red";// Or Green
```

Then when you loop through just check for the description of the imagecell and do your stuff

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
  if(row.Cells[2] is DataGridViewImageCell)
  {
     if((row.Cells[2] as DataGridViewImageCell).Description == "Red")
     { // your stuff}
  }
}
```